# $f(x)\bmod b$: solve for $ x$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse-function

Is there a way to solve this for $x$ ? $$y=(ax^2+a-x)\bmod 2a^2$$
How to handle this kind of equation?
From what I read, even a simpler form seems to be far from simple.

When $a$ is odd, $y$ is odd, and I am only interested in $a$ odd for now. For a fixed odd $a$, each (integer $\ge 0$) value of $x<a^2$ maps $1$ to $1$ to an odd $y<2a^2$. Since there is a direct map, I think it is possible to reverse it. If it is only feasible with a prime, I can do with tha.t

Comment: Even for quadratics where you can complete the square modulo $n$ it is hard to find a closed form. But here, you can’t even do that, because you have to invert $a$ modulo $2a^2$ to complete the square, which isn’t possible.

Comment: In general, for polynomial congruences modulo $n$, one starts by factoring $n$ into its prime-power factors and using the Chinese remainder theorem to reduce to the same congrunce modulo prime powers. What do you know about $a$?

Comment: @Greg Martin, When $a$ is odd, $y$ is odd, and I am only interested in $a$ odd for now. For a fixed odd $a$, each (integer >= 0) value of $x<a^2$ maps 1to1 to an odd $y<2a^2$. Since there is a direct map, I think it is possible to reverse it. If it is only feasible with $a$ prime, I can do with that.

Comment: Great—the information that the map is empirically one-to-one is probably important enough to mention in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\!\bmod \color{#0a0}{a^2}\!: \overbrace{\color{#c00}f(\color{#c00}f(x)) \equiv x}^{\large f(x) \,:=\, ax^2-x+a}\!\!\!,\ $ so $\,\ f(x)\equiv y\iff x\equiv f(y),\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{f\ \text{self-inverse}}$.

$\!\bmod \color{darkorange}2\!:\ \ a\equiv 1,\,\ x^2\equiv x\,\Rightarrow\, f(x)\equiv 1\,$ so $\,f(x)\equiv y\,$  is solvable $\!\iff\! y$ is odd.

So by $\,\gcd(\color{darkorange}2,\color{#0a0}a^2)\!=\!1,\,$ CRT $\Rightarrow f(x)\equiv y\pmod{\!\color{darkorange}2\color{#0a0}{a^2}}\,$ is solvable $\!\iff\! y\,$ is odd, with solution  $\,x\equiv f(y)\pmod{\!a^2}\,$ or, equivalently, $\, x\,\equiv\, f(y),\ f(y)\!+\!a^2\pmod{\!2a^2}$

---

**Remark** $ $ Though it is easy to verify by calculation that $\,f\,$ is self-inverse, it can be viewed more generally as the special case $\,g(x)= x^2+1\,$ of the following simple self-inverse criterion, which shows that the self-inverse $\,f(x)\equiv -x\pmod{\!a}\,$ has a lift $\,f(x)\equiv -x+a\:\!g(x)\pmod{a^2}\,$ that persists self-inverse $\!\iff\! g(x)\,$ is even $\!\bmod a,\,$ i.e. $\,g(-x)\equiv g(x)\pmod{\!a}$.

$\begin{align}{\bf Lemma}\quad\ \  \color{0darkorange}{\rm if}\ \ &y\equiv f(x)\ {\overset{\rm\color{darkorange} H}\equiv}\:\! -x+a\:\!g(x)\!\! \pmod{\!a^2},\ \ {\rm for}\ g\in \Bbb Z[x]\\[.2em]
{\rm  then}\ \ & x\equiv f(y)\!\!\!\pmod{\!a^2}\!\iff\! g(-x)\equiv g(x)\!\!\!\pmod{\!a}\end{align}$

$\begin{align}{\bf Proof}_{\,1}\  &\bmod \color{#c00}a^2\!:\,\ 0 \equiv  \color{#c00}a(g(f(x))-g(x))\equiv f(f(x))-x\,\\[-.1em] 
\overset{{\rm cancel}\ \color{#c00}a}\iff\ \  &\bmod a\!:\,\  \ \ 0 \ \,\equiv\,\ g(\color{#0a0}{f(x)})-g(x) \equiv g(\color{#0a0}{-x})-g(x)\ \ {\rm by}\ \  \color{#0a0}{f(x)\equiv -x}
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
{\bf Proof}_{\,2}\quad\ \color{0darkorange}{\rm if}\ \ \ &0\equiv f(x)-y\:\!\ \smash[t]{{\overset{\rm\color{darkorange} H}\equiv}} -x-y+a\:\!g(x)\pmod{a^2}\\[.2em]
{\rm then}\ \ \  &0 \equiv f(y)-x = -y-x+a\:\!g(y),\,\ \ \rm so\ subtracting\\[.2em]
\iff\ &0\equiv a(g(x)-g(y)),\, {\rm but} \ a(\color{#0a0}{x+y})\ \smash[t]{{\overset{\rm\color{darkorange} H}\equiv}}\:\!\ a^2g(x)\equiv 0,\ \rm so \\[.2em]
\smash[t]{\overset{\rm\color{#0af} R}\iff}\ \ &0\equiv a(g(x)-g(\color{#c00}y)\ \ \,\bmod\ \ \color{#0a0}{x+y})\\[.2em]
\iff\ &0\equiv a(g(x)-g(\color{#c00}{-x}))\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}{y\equiv -x}\!\!\!\pmod{\!\color{#0a0}{x+y}}\\[.2em]
\iff\ &0\equiv\ \ \  g(x)-g(-x)\!\!\pmod{\!a},\ \ {\rm by\ cancelling}\,\ a
\end{align}$

by $\,\rm\color{#0af}  R\!:\:$ if $\,a\color{#0a0}e\equiv 0\,$ and $\,n\equiv \bar n\pmod{\!\color{#0a0}e}\,$ then $\,an\equiv 0\!\iff\! a\bar n\equiv 0\,$ [[order Reduction]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242), where above we have $\,\color{#0a0}{e=x+y},\,$ $\,n = g(x)-g(y),\,$ $\,\bar n := n\bmod e$.

Comment: Very nice. It seems to also be valid for $a$ even (with f(x) mod $a^2$)

Comment: @user489810 Yes, it's easy to tweak the $\!\bmod 2\,$ case to be general (and also to generalize further - see my remark above).

Answer (score 1):

Let's first consider the slightly different congruence $y\equiv ax^2+a-x\pmod{a^2}$ rather than $\pmod{2a^2}$.

Every $x\pmod{a^2}$ can be uniquely written as $x=av-w$ where $0\le v\le a-1$ and $0\le w\le a-1$. (The strange choice of $av-w$ rather than $av+w$ makes a later formula come out more nicely in hindsight.) Using this substitution gives
\begin{align*}
ax^2+a-x &= a(av-w)^2+a-(av-w) \\
&= a^3 v^2- a^2(2 v w)+a (w^2+1-v)+w \\
&\equiv a (w^2+1-v)+w \pmod{a^2}.
\end{align*}
So if we want to see what value of $x$ yields a particular value of $y\pmod{a^2}$, we can write $y=as+t$ for some $0\le s\le a-1$ and $0\le t\le a-1$. Then we should set $w=t$ and (after a tiny bit of algebra) $v \equiv t^2+1-s\pmod{a^2}$.

If we want to reach a particular odd value of $y\pmod{2a^2}$, we should use the above recipe if $1\le y\le a^2$, or the above recipe applied to $y'=y-a^2$.

Comment: It's much simpler since $f(x)$ is self-inverse - see my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I think you saved my question (which was starting to have "vote to close"). Bill's answer is simpler, but you gave me some insight for other cases.

Comment: @user489810 What saved your question from being closed was likely the context I added from your comment. Note that I added a remark to my answer showing how to view it as lifting the obviously self inverse $\,f(x)\equiv -x\,$ from $\!\bmod a\,$ up to $\!\bmod a^2,\,$ similar to [Newton's method (Hensel lifting)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3842844/242).