# Show that if $x$ is an integer, then $x^{10} \equiv \{-1, 0 ,1\} \pmod{25}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that if $x$ is an integer, then $x^{10} \equiv \{-1, 0 ,1\} \pmod{25}$

Well, the first case if $(25, x)$ is not 1, so $x$ is a multiple of $5$ and $x^{10} \equiv 0$.

If $(25, x) =1$, $x^{20} \equiv 1$ by Euler's Theorem.

I am just learning number theory, how can we jump from that to $x^{10} \equiv 1$ or $-1$?

Comment: It might be helpful to note that $x^{20} = (x^{10})^2$…

Comment: That inference is proved in the linked dupes more generally for modulus $p^2$ for odd prime $\,p\ \ $

Comment: More generally see [Hensel Lifting (Newton's Method)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3842844/242).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^{20} \equiv 1 \pmod{25}$ implies $25 \mid (x^{10}-1)(x^{10}+1)$. Try to work from that.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: note that, for $x$ integer, $$x^2=\{1,0,-1\} \pmod 5$$

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

If $d=(x,25)=1$, then by Euler's Theorem we have $$x^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{ 25}\implies x^{10}\equiv \pm 1\pmod 5$$
That would mean $x^{10}\pm 1\equiv 0\pmod 5$ Hence$$ (x^{10}\pm 1)^2=x^{20}\pm 2x^{10}+1\equiv 2\pm 2\equiv 0 \text{ or }-1\pmod {25}$$

Now if $d\ne 1$ then $x\equiv 0\pmod 5\implies x^2\equiv 0\pmod{25}\implies x^{10}\equiv 0\pmod{25}$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).