# Hensel's Lemma when the polynomial does not have a simple root

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I haven't been able to find a 'multiple root version's of the Hensel's Lemma so below is my attempt at proving it using the generalized form of Hensel's Lemma:

**Statement**: Let $A$ be a complete discrete valuation ring and uniformizer $\pi$. Let $k = A/ \mathfrak{m}$ be it's residue field. Let $f(x) \in A[x]$ be such that its image in $k[x]$, $\bar{f}$ has a root $a_0$ of multiplicity $e$. Then there exists a unique root $a$ of $f$ with $a \equiv a_0 \pmod{\pi^e}$.

Proof: We have, $\bar{f}(x) = (x-a_0)^e h_0(x)$ where $h_0(a_0) \neq 0$ in $k$. 
By the general version of Hensel's Lemma, we can write $ f(x) = g(x) h(x)$ where $\bar{g} = (x-a_0)^e, \bar{h} = h_0$. 
We note that deg$(g)= e$.

Let $\alpha \in A$ such that $\bar{\alpha} = a_0 \pmod{\pi}$.  Then $\alpha = a_0+a_1 \pi + a_2 \pi^2 + ... $
 I'm not sure how to proceed from here. So I'd appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

Also, is the statement I've written above correct?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you looked [at this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90692/hensels-lemma-fx-equiv-0-pmodp-case/90856#90856) for the case with $f'(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin just did, now. Thank you for the link and the answer there! Can it be generalized to the case of a complete local ring $A$? I suppose that the proof doesn't change much?

Comment: I haven't really thought about it; there may be subtleties involved, of couse.